# Having problems with the MergeAdapter

Tags: android, commonsware-cwac

When using Mark Murphy's MergeAdapter everything compiles fine, but when the ListView binding occurs I get a crash with the following error when calling the addAdapter() method:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.commonsware.cwac.sacklist.SackOfViewsAdapter`

The SackOfViewsAdapter jar file does exist within libs dir of the cwac-merge project.

I have checked out the demo project that comes with the project and I can't see anything that it has that I don't, although I get NoClassDefFoundError exceptions when I try to run it.

I have a feeling this is an Eclipse configuration issue, but I have tried everything that I can think of.

Any ideas?

** Update: the SackOfViewsAdapter also shows up as a referenced library in the cwac-merge project.

** Update 2: My .classpath:

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="/Users/colsen/Projects/android/cwac-merge/libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

** Update 3 - copied SackOfViewsAdapter to local libs dir.

```
<classpath>
    <classpathentry kind="lib" path="libs/CWAC-SackOfViewsAdapter.jar"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
    <classpathentry kind="src" path="gen"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.ANDROID_FRAMEWORK"/>
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.LIBRARIES"/>
    <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin/classes"/>
</classpath>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The SackOfViewsAdapter jar file does exist within libs dir of the cwac-merge project.

It looks like you need to also add `SackOfViewsAdapter.jar` to your Eclipse build path of the project *using* `MergeAdapter`. Even though the library project's reference to this works at compile time, it will not work at runtime.

I just updated the `demo/` Eclipse project files to reflect this.

My apologies for the difficulty.

Comment: Hey Mark,  I did previously try to reference the jar file directly from my project, but still couldn't get it to work.  I updated the question to show my .classpath file which seems to match your on the commit you just made. https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-merge/commit/d93d797eafae347e12714a25224b02ec96c687e7

Comment: @chris: Try copying the `SackOfViewsAdapter` JAR into your hosting project and adding it to your build path, instead of referencing the one from your `cwac-merge` directory. I also just realized that the error I was seeing was a bit different, complaining about missing `MergeAdapter$EnabledSackAdapter`.

Comment: As shown in the .classpath above I tried moving the jar to the libs folder, but I still get the same error.  I have also tried moving the merge.jar file to the libs dir as well, but it still fails (I then get a simular error but for the MergeAdapter jar file).  I have also tried playing with the order of the libs in the include list, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @chris: ::shrug:: You have me stumped. On a whim, try an Ant build. That has always worked (mostly because I wrote `MergeAdapter` before having my arm twisted to use Eclipse... :-)

Comment: So what I forgot to mention was that I have one central *common* project that is being used by 2 different apps.  I was copying the jar file to the common project and not the individual child projects.  All is working now whether or not I reference the jar file within the cwac-merge project or the local one.  Thanks for the help Mark.